# cannot instantiate concrete class in Julia

Tags: julia

I am just getting started with Julia and have defined a module as follows:

**MyModule.jl**

```
module MyModule
export ConcreteClass
end
```

Then I have a file which defined some trivial abstract class as:

**generics.jl**

```
abstract MyAbstract
```

After this I try and inherit this class:

**concrete.jl**

```
type ConcreteClass <: MyAbstract

end
```

Of course, this is trivial but I just wanted to be able to instantiate a trivial example. I added the path to my project sources to the `LOAD_PATH` variable and in my julia console i ran the following:

```
using MyModule   # No error
r = ConcreteClass()
```

The second line fails with: `ERROR: UndefVarError: ConcreteClass not defined`. The thing in the Julia console when I type the second line the autocomplete does suggest `ConcreteClass`, so the type is recognized but not sure why the `not defined` error comes.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. I was missing some `include` statements which seem to be necessary.

**MyModule.jl**

```
module MyModule
export ConcreteClass
include("concrete.jl")
end
```

**concrete.jl**

```
include("generics.jl")
type ConcreteClass <: MyAbstract

end
```

After adding these lines:

```
r = ConcreteClass()  # works fine
```

Comment: Personally, I put all of the includes in the MyModule.jl. You just need to make sure you include generics.jl before concrete.jl. Just a style thing.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thank you for that. Just started playing with the language today and sort of learning by doing :) Good to know.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I have one comment though. This way I hide the `MyAbstract` class from the library user and they cannot mistakenly try to instantiate it. Is that something worth considering?

Comment: There's no reason to hide it. It's an abstract type. Julia users will know not to do that. If you want to be safe, you can append `Abstract` to the beginning of the name: that's a common idiom. But this is better solved by documentation, not by hiding.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I see. So, in this way it follows the python philosophy. I somehow still think that if you can hide undefined behaviour from the user, it has its advantages.